# Default fonts in browser are not as expected

Tags: fonts

When opening the developer tools in my browser I see that `-apple-system` & `BlinkMacSystemFont` is prepended to the font-family and manually removing this seems to fix the issue on some sites.

When using instagram web app (many other sites as well) here is what the text looks like:

[Strange font example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzfbD.png)

Not quite sure what is happening but this problem seems to have come with setting up my second monitor. This issue also occurs in firefox as well.

Just wondering how I can get my default fonts back. Each browser's default is setup as DejaVu Sans

EDIT:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS

I have also tried disabling fractional scaling and restarting my system with no luck.

After running command mentioned by @Gunnar Hjalmarsson:

Output:

```
jordan@jordan-pc:~$ fc-match -s | head -5
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
FreeMono.ttf: "FreeMono" "Regular"
FreeSans.ttf: "FreeSans" "Regular"
FreeSerif.ttf: "FreeSerif" "Regular"
opens___.ttf: "OpenSymbol" "Regular"
AnjaliOldLipi-Regular.ttf: "AnjaliOldLipi" "Regular"
```

While debugging before this step I manually deleted `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS and the second browser is google chrome

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `fc-match -s | head -5`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Please see my edits, I believe the first error is from my deleting of `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

Comment: You seem to have messed it up. _DejaVu Sans_ is the default font in Ubuntu, and should have showed up first when running that command. Why on earth did you delete the default config file?